# How to immediately forget last sudo usage

Tags: c++, sudo

I am trying, in C++, to write a program that will request sudo privilege if it does not have it.  I have accomplished that through `execl("/usr/bin/sudo", "sudo", argv[0]);` but my biggest problem is occurring in trying to test it.  Is there a way to make the system forget that I have recently used `sudo` so I can run and request access again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo -k  invalidates the credentials.

Edit:

There is sudo -K (capital K) command that you can invoke to invalidate the credentials, but the -k flag can be used by prepending it to argv (maybe even based on the build configuration)

Comment: Thank you! Sad to say, I've used that flag before and just entirely forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps to change the default timeout.
sudo visudo

scroll down and add the following line at the end:
Defaults:user_name timestamp_timeout=0

1) Change user_name to your actual user name.

2) Change 10 (in minutes) to anything you wish. A value of -1 will make it infinite (for a single session).

3) Hit Ctrl-X and then hit Y.
You are all set!

[Reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/sudo-not-prompt-for-password-anymore-when-reexecuted/)